# Imported package not found

Tags: python

I am completely new to Python so apologies for the question. I imported a package inside a virtual environment that I created but when I try to run a test.py file inside the venv, it says that there was no module found.

The structure of my files are:

```
├── .venv
│   ├── bin
    ├── include
    ├── lib
        └── site_packages (where my module is installed)
    ├── test.py
```

I am not sure if this is an issue related to the PYTHONPATH or related to the fact that they are not in the same location?

Comment: If the package is installed, it should be available to scripts anywhere, as long as the virtual environment is active. Please explain what package was installed, how you installed it and how you run your `test.py` script

Comment: The package name is twillio and I installed it from the terminal using the command pip install twillio. I run the test.py script via using VS Code.

Comment: I suspect that the problem lies to the $PATH I gave. How can I make sure that I am using the correct python path?

Comment: You don't generally need to worry about that yourself, it's something you *can* change if you need to, but rarely have to if you use the software in the intended way. Do you have this problem with all packages? Have you looked at a basic tutorial on how to set up VSCode for use with Python?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.